# How to ignore trailing slash while joining two string columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, slash, trailing

I have two tables tableA and tableB as described bellow

```
desc tableA
GUID
PROPERTY_NAME
PROPERY_VALUE
ANOTHER_COL_1
ANTHER_COL_2

desc tableB
GUID
PROPERY_NAME
PROPERTY_VALUE
RANDOM_COL_1
RANDOME_COL_2
```

I have the following query to fetch the list of entries which have matching values for property_name which here is "URL"

```
SELECT A.GUID as SOURCE_GUID, 
       B.GUID as DESTINATION_GUID 
FROM
       tableA A,
       tableB B
WHERE
       A.PROPERTY_NAME = "URL" AND
       A.PROPERY_NAME  = B.PROPERTY_NAME AND
       A.PROPERTY_VALUE = B.PROPERTY_VALUE
```

The issue here is as propery values are URLs, they may or may not have trailing slash. I want the join to happen regardless of trailing slash. Please suggest a better way of achieving the same with out using an PL/SQL procedures to remove the trailing slash.

Comment: "Please suggest a better way of achieving the same with out using an PL/SQL procedures to remove the trailing slash"  Translation: *I have poor data quality processes but I want to keep them because I like creating work for myself.*

Answer (score 7):

You have two options.

The first is clean your data before use.

Before any URL is stored in the system, add or remove (as prefered) a slash if necessary.  In this way ensure that all URLs are stored in the same format for ease of use.

The second is clean your data at run time.

I do not advocate these options as they incur unnecessary overheads and can prevent optimal use of indexes.

```
RTRIM(A.PROPERTY_VALUE, '/') = RTRIM(B.PROPERTY_VALUE, '/')
```

Cleanest code, but likely prevent index use.

- Values from both Table A and Table B are being modified
- This likely requires a SCAN on both tables

Or...

- (Ensure B.PROPERTY_VALUE ends with '/', then do the comparison); OR
- (Ensure B.PROPERTY_VALUE does NOT end with '/', then do the comparison)

If either of these conditions are true, the URLs match.

```
A.PROPERTY_VALUE = (CASE WHEN RIGHT(B.PROPERTY_VALUE, 1) = '/' THEN B.PROPERTY_VALUE ELSE B.PROPERTY_VALUE + '/' END)
OR
A.PROPERTY_VALUE = (CASE WHEN RIGHT(B.PROPERTY_VALUE, 1) = '/' THEN RTRIM(B.PROPERTY_VALUE, '/') ELSE B.PROPERTY_VALUE END)
```

Much messier, but May be more index friendly

- Only the B table values are being altered
- a SCAN on B is necessary
- an INDEX SEEK on A is now possible

Comment: +1 for data cleansing upfront.  Otherwise, if we insist on loading shonky data we have to handle it *every time we use it*.

Comment: Then you really, Really, want to start cleaning up your data when it's being loaded.  That way you can encapsulate your "clean-up" code in one place, AND using that data then becomes ALOT more performant.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily remove trailing slashes using the RTRIM function:

```
...
AND RTRIM(A.PROPERTY_VALUE,'/') = RTRIM(B.PROPERTY_VALUE,'/')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT A.GUID as SOURCE_GUID, 
       B.GUID as DESTINATION_GUID 
FROM   tableA A,
       tableB B
WHERE  A.PROPERTY_NAME = "URL"
AND    A.PROPERY_NAME = B.PROPERTY_NAME
AND    RTRIM(A.PROPERTY_VALUE, '/') = RTRIM(B.PROPERTY_VALUE, '/')
```

Comment: ...I take it you realise that you need `AND`s in the `where` clause. It might be a bit more efficient to do an inner join rather than a cross join, too.

Comment: He has `AND` at the end of the lines.

Comment: Xophmeister: At least in the Oracle world, that's just syntactic sugar, the query optimizer takes care of the execution plan anyway.