# SQL: If some rows in column returns null, then query again

Tags: sql

I need to join 2 tables together on the 'URL' column, however because of some crazy problems on our back-end, the URLs get logged inconsistently (slash/no-slash) in the two tables: `http://google.com/` vs. `http://google.com`.

After I run my query to join, I get:

```
URL                     DATE
http://facebook.com     20130914
http://google.com/      NULL
http://youtube.com/     NULL
```

I'm a beginner with SQL, but does SQL have something like after you run a query, IF item in column is empty, then run query again?

I found [How to ignore trailing slash while joining two string columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308917/how-to-ignore-trailing-slash-while-joining-two-string-columns-in-sql) that I can then modify the 2nd query to remove trailing slash if exist.

Comment: What does your query look like?  Why not join using rtrim(col,'/')?  Not efficient, but probably more efficient than querying twice.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: the reason is because I only want to rtrim if what it returned null on the first pass

Comment: SELECT
      DISTINCT b.url AS url,
      a.date AS date
    FROM url_results a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN url_samples b
    ON b.url = a.url;

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your best best course of action is to cleanup the data and normalize it on insert. The problem here is that you are performing a join with this data. Any work around will be very inefficient from a performance perspective.